# Using ES modules installed via npm without a module packer like parcel/webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, openlayers, es6-modules

I am trying to understand how ES modules and node modules are working together.
I wanted to use OpenLayers (ol) and I tried to use it without a JavaScript module packer like parcel/webpack or similar.
The reason to avoid a module packer is simply to understand how modules are working, to integrate it more easy in my django app and to avoid another layer of complexity.
But I ran into problems and wonder if it is worth the time to try.
Is some module packer "necessary" to use node modules?

### My case

I followed [this tutorial](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/), but I avoided parcel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Using Parcel with OpenLayers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/ol/ol.css">
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./node_modules/ol/Map.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./node_modules/ol/View.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./node_modules/ol/layer/Tile.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./node_modules/ol/source/OSM.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import Map from './node_modules/ol/Map.js';
        import View from './node_modules/ol/View.js';
        import TileLayer from './node_modules/ol/layer/Tile.js';
        import OSM from './node_modules/ol/source/OSM.js';

        const map = new Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 0
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I get `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: rbush`. So I guess openlayers depends heavily on some packaging tool and is not useable without it. Is that right?

Comment: A possible workaround in the final comment here https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8552